# GitHub Failed to push my code to remote

Tags: android, github

Here is my difficulty when I push my changes to remote today (by using Android Studio)

Here is my commands:

```
git add *
git commit -m "***"
git push
```

Later,the terminal publish some informations below, and I was confused by those although I had try kinds of methods that I could search. But they were not working!!

[image]

Can someone help me???

Comment: fix your .gitignore ... you shouldn push files from any .xxxx (.gradle in your case)

Comment: still not working and my .gitignore has already include .bin...

Comment: The problem is you try to push some large file (more then 100 mb). You need to exclude it or use LFS.

Comment: You also need to include `.gradle` in your gitignore, _in addition to_ your `.bin`, is what Selvin is saying.

Comment: already include .gradle in my gitignore >.<